# Node/Mongoose .populate() model after a POST and returning 201 created

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

Using a typical example of POST'ing a `Post`, everything seems to be working as expected, and it's saving the `User` ObjectId in the Database etc.

When it **returns the results, I can't seem to get it to populate the User though**

```
Posts.createAsync(req.body)
    .then(saveUpdates(req.body))
    .then(responseWithResult(res, 201));


function saveUpdates(updates) {
    return function (entity) {
        var updated = _.merge(entity, updates);
        return updated.saveAsync()
        .spread(function (updated) {
            return updated;
        });
    };
}
```

Here's where I need it to just re-populate and return the full `Post` model with the populated `User`

```
function responseWithResult(res, statusCode) {
    statusCode = statusCode || 200;

    return function (entity) {
        if (entity) {
            // Here's where I've tried just about everything I can think of

            // entity.populate('user') (doesn't work)

            res.status(statusCode).json(entity);
        }
    };
}
```

---

> Note: In a GET everything works and it populates the `User`, but for some reason the typical `.populate().execAsync()` doesn't seem to work here...

```
Posts.find({ "team" : req.params.id})
    .populate({ path: 'user' })
    .execAsync(function (err, posts) {
        res.json(posts);
});
```

What am I missing in the POST return?

---

The models aren't anything fancy, basically just:

```
var PostsSchema = new Schema({
    user : {
        type: Schema.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User'
    },
    message : String
});

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    // etc etc
});
```

Comment: Isn't `.execAsync()` supposed to be returning a promise? You're using a callback here for some reason.

Comment: The example below was just showing another area where .populate works. How can I do it within the `.createAsync() .saveAsync()` area? @BlakesSeven